# How do I check If the mouse cursor is hovering over something clickable?

Tags: c#, mouseevent

How can I achieve that when the mouse cursor hovers over a search bar (so the hand with a finger pointing appears) the console application does something?

Something like this:

```
if (mousecursor == clickable) {
     Console.WriteLine("mouse cursor is hovering over something");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an event `public event EventHandler MouseHover` and `public event EventHandler MouseLeave`. You can set it in properties

Comment: I have looked at everything and from what I'm seeing is that you can use this only on your own form/program.This is hard to explain, but I would like something to happen when the mouse hovers over something in a nother porgram in other words when the "Link select" mouse cursor icon appears https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn742466(v=vs.85).aspx (here you can see what I mean with link select) and I'm sorry for responding so late I was away.